# CSS - Footer height -> scroll issue

Tags: css, xhtml, footer

I've read every post and google result about footer's height but I'm not able to fix this issue.

You can see my index here:
http://adamaweb.com/faqme/
As you can see, I want the footer extends to the end of the page. It's not a sticky footer, I just want it to extend.
But when you load the web you can see a big vertical scroll.

I thinks it appears because of the height:100% in the footer. 
It is possible to extend the footer without the scroll issue?

Comment: Give the footer `overflow: hidden;` instead of `height: 100%;`

Comment: have you tried something like the following - for your style: `#footer {
clear: both;
height: 75px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 50px 210px;
background-color: black;
}` or do `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Yes the problem is definitive your fixed height of 100% on the footer. I see no option to change the height dynamically without the use of javascript.

Comment: Thanks all. @andy then the footer doesn't expand. J.Wells nice one but if I resize the window the footer overlap the content.

Comment: @user1872795 What do you mean it doesn't expand? When I do it it fills the rest of the page

Comment: you dont need to apply any more css to the footer. check my answer below. I've had this problem before. and its 100% sure to work. Your problem is with the two floating column divs. Adding 100% height to css is making your footer the height of the browser height.

Comment: doesn't expand vertically. Maybe we're using differente browsers? I'm on Chrome

Comment: Hey JCBiggar, thank you. But you see the footer doesn't expand right?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dark footer background on the `body`. Then you need to add a 100% wide wrapper for the page content and use the light background on the new wrapper.

And yes, as per comments, you need to remove `height:100%;` from the footer.

Comment: Yep, I thought that workaround too but I would like to se if there is another way withouth changing the div structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your html background to the same as your footer:

```
   html, body {
     margin:0;
     background:black;
   }
```